# how to link a file and folder so that if i delete one both are deleted

Tags: html, windows, file, google-chrome

If I save a website in chrome by hitting "ctrl+s" then it generates a html file and a folder containing the image and other static resources.

But if I delete only the html file then the folder also gets deleted, how does Windows handles this process? Is it linked with some symlink commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's some (weird) behaviour in explorer. When you delete the HTML file with the command line the folder will not be deleted.
To avoid this simply rename one of the files (more information in the [source](https://superuser.com/questions/1337772/windows-deletes-html-files-when-i-delete-a-folder))